# Switching a parametric form of a plane to a non-parametric form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have a parameterized representation of a plane:

$$ (1,0,2) + t(-1,0,1) + u(0,1,3) : t ϵ R, u ϵ R $$

I want to swicth it to the equation $ax + by + cz = d$ in order to find the intersection line with a plane given by the equation $x + 2y + 3z = 6$

I know how to do it for a line in $R^2$ but I guess it is not the same for plane.

can anybody give a hint?

Comment: For parametrized plane, x = 1-t, y = u and z = 2+t+3u. Write t in terms of x then z in terms of x and y.

Answer (score 0):

You have $(x,y,z)=(1,0,2)+t(-1,0,1)+u(0,1,3)$
which yelds a system of equations:
\begin{equation}
x=1-t\\
y=u\\
z=2+t+3u
\end{equation}
You have to solve the system for $u$ and $t$ using one line at a time. In the end you will have your cartesian equation.